# Can one React Native screen be included in two different stack navigators?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator, react-native-tabnavigator

Is there any reason a screen shouldn't be included in two different stack navigators?

I would like it in both stack navigators to have a smooth, in-flow page transition and back button to smoothly go back to the previous page. In example below, `ContactScreen` appears twice:

```
const StackOne = createStackNavigator({
  About: AboutScreen,
  FAQ: FAQScreen,
  Contact: ContactScreen
});

const StackTwo = createStackNavigator({
  Main: MainScreen,
  Details: DetailsScreen
  Contact: ContactScreen
});

const MainTabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
  TabOne: StackOne,
  TabTwo: StackTwo
});
```

Comment: If you set RouteName differently, this code will not be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can use the same screen in different stack navigators . follow this example:

> .js file

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home!</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Settings"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Settings')}
        />
        <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Settings!</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Home"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
        />
        <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Details!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Details: { screen: DetailsScreen },
});

const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator({
  Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen },
  Details: { screen: DetailsScreen },
});

export default createAppContainer(createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeStack },
    Settings: { screen: SettingsStack },
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === 'Home') {
          iconName = `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
        } else if (routeName === 'Settings') {
          iconName = `ios-options${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
        }

        // You can return any component that you like here! We usually use an
        // icon component from react-native-vector-icons
        return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
      },
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'tomato',
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    },
  }
));
```